# Adding some logic to SQL query

Tags: sql

First of all I'm really not that great at sql, with that said, onwards to the question:

Lets say I have a table called Abilities.
In this example Abilities has a ID, PersonID, Text.

Lets say I do a search where I specify that I want to distinct list every person that has the ability to 'Fly', 'Drive', 'Sing' but do NOT have the ability to 'Fight', 'Skateboard'

Is there anyway to write such a query which in the end will only return the rows that match my above statement? The table and it's contents is purely fictional I might add, hence the wierdness :P

I would really appreciate help with this as it's for a rather complex search utility for a database.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want all the abilities (included or excluded) or any of the include list and any of the exclude list? Makes a bit of a difference to what is required and what will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT a.PersonId
FROM Abilities a
JOIN Abilities b ON (a.PersonId = b.PersonId AND b.text = 'Drive')
JOIN Abilities c ON (a.PersonId = c.PersonId AND c.text = 'Sing')
LEFT JOIN Abilities d ON (a.PersonId = d.PersonId AND d.text = 'Flight')
LEFT JOIN Abilities e ON (a.PersonId = e.PersonId AND e.text = 'Skateboard')
WHERE a.text = 'Fly' AND d.Id IS NULL and e.Id IS NULL
```

I see you got several answers trying to perform both IN and NOT IN tests on the same instance of Abilities, but that can't work - you clearly need to test on separate instances of Abilities, whence the need for this multiple self-join!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the actual data and query parameters, an approach without self-joins might be more efficient.  I would expect this to do a single full scan of the table, whereas the join method would likely do many index lookups.

```
SELECT personID FROM
(
SELECT personID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN text IN ('Fly','Drive','Sing') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) good_stuff,
       SUM(CASE WHEN text IN ('Fight','Skateboard') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) bad_stuff
  FROM abilities
  GROUP BY personID
)
WHERE good_stuff = 3 and bad_stuff = 0
```

Comment: Instead of the nested query, a having clause would also work, but it would have to repeat the 'SUM's instead of being able to use the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to solve this.  I've selected one which should be readable, but not necessarily maintainable for a lot of change.

```
WITH Fliers AS (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM Abilities
    WHERE Text = 'Fly'
),
Drivers AS (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM Abilities
    WHERE Text = 'Drive'
),
Singers AS (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM Abilities
    WHERE Text = 'Sing'
),
Fighters AS (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM Abilities
    WHERE Text = 'Fight'
),
Skateboarders AS (
    SELECT PersonID
    FROM Abilities
    WHERE Text = 'Skateboard'
)
SELECT *
FROM People
INNER JOIN Fliers
    ON Fliers.PersonID = People.PersonID
INNER JOIN Drivers
    ON Drivers.PersonID = People.PersonID
INNER JOIN Singers
    ON Singers.PersonID = People.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Fighters
    ON Fighters.PersonID = People.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Skateboarders
    ON Skateboarders.PersonID = People.PersonID
WHERE Fighters.PersonID IS NULL
    AND Skateboarders.PersonID IS NULL
```

But there's lots of ways to skin this cat.

Most of the solutions here use a simple IN, NOT IN, but they are not going to give the results I think you are expecting - i.e. people who have Fly AND Drive AND Sing AND NEITHER Fight NOR Skateboard

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT PERSONID, COUNT(SKILLS)  FROM DUMMY  WHERE SKILLS IN ('FLY','DRIVE','SING') GROUP BY PERSONID HAVING COUNT(*)=3 ) A 

WHERE PERSONID NOT IN 

 ( SELECT DISTINCT PERSONID  FROM DUMMY WHERE SKILLS  IN ('FIGHT','SKATEBOARD')  )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please, [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) to improve readability.

Comment: In addition, we like to [avoid code-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) when possible.  A really good answer often includes explanations and descriptions of what you're doing and why!  Including details like that help to make the site better, and to make your own answers more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the database server, but I know this works in SQL Server

```
SELECT a1.ID, a1.PersonID, a1.Text
FROM Abilities a1
WHERE a1.Text IN ('Fly', 'Drive', 'Sing')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID
                FROM Abilities a2
                WHERE a2.ID = a1.ID
                AND a2.Text IN ('Fight', 'Skateboard'))
```